# Combine 2 datasets that have different columns and fill the value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have df1:

```
ID     B      C
1     1      a
2     2      b
3     3      c
4     1      a
```

df2:

```
ID       B
5       1
6       2
7       3
8       1
```

I want to combine them so I can get df3:

```
ID     B     C
1     1     a
2     2     b
3     3     c
4     4     d
5     1     a
6     2     b
7     3     c
8     1     a
```

ID has unique value(no repeating)
B and C have repeating values and are matched. For example, when B=1 C always equals a.

So far, I tried a different approach.
`df3=df1.merge(df2,how='outer')`
`df3=df3.groupby('B',as_index=False).fillna( method ='ffill')` but B and C are not matching.

Is there any other approaches or how to fix my current one?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need select column for forward filling and assign back:

```
df3=df1.merge(df2,how='outer')
#if missing values are in first place get them to back
df3 = df3.sort_values('C')   
df3['C'] = df3.groupby('B')['C'].ffill()
df3 = df3.sort_index()
print (df3)
   ID  B  C
0   1  1  a
1   2  2  b
2   3  3  c
3   4  1  a
4   5  1  a
5   6  2  b
6   7  3  c
7   8  1  a
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the data, and then fill the null values using a mapping of column B to column C from df1 :

```
mapping = df1.drop_duplicates("B").set_index("B").C
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).assign(C=lambda df: df.B.map(mapping))

    ID  B   C
0   1   1   a
1   2   2   b
2   3   3   c
3   4   1   a
4   5   1   a
5   6   2   b
6   7   3   c
7   8   1   a
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an error in your third screenshot if B is always the same?

If these are the correct dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [1, 2, 3, 1], "C": ["a", "b", "c", "a"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [5, 6, 7, 8], "B": [1, 2, 3, 1]})
```

Then you're very close, you just need to create the `df3["C"]` column based on the corresponding unique values in `B`:

First merge and check out the `NaNs`

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="outer")

print(df3)


   ID  B    C
0   1  1    a
1   2  2    b
2   3  3    c
3   4  1    a
4   5  1  NaN
5   6  2  NaN
6   7  3  NaN
7   8  1  NaN
```

Then create the column `C` by filling from the `B`->`C` correspondence in previous rows:

```
df3["C"] = df3.groupby("B")["C"].fillna(method="ffill")

print(df3)print(df3)print(df3)

   ID  B  C
0   1  1  a
1   2  2  b
2   3  3  c
3   4  1  a
4   5  1  a
5   6  2  b
6   7  3  c
7   8  1  a
```